# How can you access the rails errors array from within a lambda in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, error-handling, controller

I'm trying to access the errors array to display in my view, but I'm writing to it inside a lambda within the model. I keep getting:

```
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `errors'
```

Here's my code for my model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries,
  :reject_if => lambda {
    "validation here"
    errors[:base] = "You can't do that" #this line raises the above error
  }
```

Outside of the lambda (in the model itself), the errors work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you're setting the value, you'll have to use `self.` here

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries,
  :reject_if => lambda {
    "validation here"
    self.errors[:base] = "You can't do that" #this line raises the above error
  }
```

Comment: Actually I tried that, but it doesn't work either. I also tried calling it directly on the class.